# Paperclip Only Showing Default Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Pretty new to ruby on rails and experimenting with some new gems.

So I have an issue with paperclip only loading the default image.  No matter if I choose one or not.

Here is my code.
Schema

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "password_digest"
t.string   "remember_token"
t.boolean  "admin",              default: false
t.string   "image_file_name"
t.string   "image_content_type"
t.integer  "image_file_size"
t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

user model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },      :default_url => "/images/emptyuser.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

call in the show.html.erb

```
      <p>
        <%= image_tag @user.image.url(:medium) %>
      </p>
```

user controller

```
  def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
if @user.save
  sign_in @user
 flash[:success] = "Welcome to My App?!"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'new'
end
end
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
  redirect_to @user
else
  render 'edit'
end
    private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                               :password_confirmation, :image)
end
```

I'm pretty sure I had it working, and then when I added the default image I broke it, and now when I go back I can't get it to work..

Anyone know why my images aren't uploading and only the default url is being loaded?

I think I need some sleep. Sorry if this is a dumb fix, but I appreciate your help.

EDIT:  Thanks for the link @hunteros I somehow missed that in the doc.  It is being saved now to the default location. I will check to see if explicitly changing them does the trick.

EDIT#2: 
Would this be the proper syntax and pathing? 
Added to model user.rb

```
   :path  => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:image/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
    :url => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:image/:id_partition/:style/:filename"
```

The actual file structure is as follows: system/:class/images(is this :image?)/000(not sure here)/001/:style/actual file finally

Seems a little intense.  Couldn't they just all go in one damn directory..?

```
:path  => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename",
:url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename"
```

when I call user.image I get the path, and it seems to match up but I still see default i mage.
Image URL: /system/users/images/medium/sarahanddee.JPG?1394522170

are the numbers at the end of the string a problem?

Comment: can you try to add a bit more information about where it might be going wrong? for example, do you see the files actually saved in the /public/system/users/images within your Rails app directory? And what is happening in your controller when you try to handle the user creation? are the users saved properly just without images?

Comment: also try explicitly specifying the `:path` and/or `:url` as explained [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#understanding-storage) to make sure you know where it is trying to save the uploads

Comment: I notice it now.  I'm not sure how to access them via the url => option.  I'm not too familiar with rails.  See edit #2 in comment

Comment: In the past, I've used `:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename"` and `:url => "/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename"`. Changing `:image` to `:attachment` and getting rid of `:id_partition` will clean up the path a little bit. For `:url`, start your path with the `/system` rather than `:rails_root`

Comment: :attachment is a placeholder there in my case :image, yeah?

Comment: that's right. Using the colon specifies it as dynamic, I believe you could use `<beginning of path>/image/<rest of path>` (without the colon) the same way as you would use `<beginning of path>/:attachment/<rest of path>`

Comment: but if the images are uploading properly to the correct place and are still not showing up, then it seems like the User records are not saving properly. What are the `image_file_name` fields for the User records saved in your database?

Comment: I posted them in schema.rb? or something else?

Comment: just  <%= form.file_field :image %>

Comment: You could use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem

Comment: sorry @Peege151 I meant what values are being saved in the database for those image fields (`image_file_name`, etc). I believe Paperclip only shows the default image if those are blank; otherwise it will use the specified url, even if it doesn't exist at the specified path (it will just show a broken image in that case, not the default)

Comment: the file upload is confirmed in the database as x_file_name, x_content_type is image/jpg x_file_size is 200k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to remove the @ from @user.image.url

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never code when you're tired. It's my opinion that you must be well-rested in order to create truly efficient & compelling software

Secondly, you need to test your upload process to see if your image is being uploaded. If it's present in your db, the issue will be with how you're calling the image, else it will be a problem with the upload process

Your `default_url` looks fine to me - perhaps you could upload some logs of the requests your app is making each time it shows the "default" images?

Comment: What's the best way to do this?  When running the server, I only see:   Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (76.8ms)
It doesn't mention either the default image or a 404 for the other one. WHen playing in the console, I can verify that the image_file_name is present, and it's in my local directory.  We're sure the path is good?